# iReport stops responding when having texts in Persian

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a strange problem, we have been working with iReport and JasperReports 1.2.8 for a long time and everyone was happy in our team.

In our new project we planned to upgrade iReport and JasperReports, so we started with latest release which is 4.6.

As a test I create a blank report, put a static text in it and everything is fine, but when I edit the static text and put some Persian text in it, I can not edit the contents anymore.

Every time I try to edit the content of the static text, iReport stops responding, when I monitor it in Windows Task Manager, I see 25% CPU usage for iReport (I have a 4 core CPU) and memory usage of the iReport starts growing, and I can not do anything more but killing its process.

I have downgraded iReports to 4.5.1, 4.1.3, 4.0.1, 3.7.6, and I encountered the same problem.

How can I fix this problem? Has anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: Do you have a problem when you put some text on English? Did you try to use different fonts?

Comment: If the problem is truly with Static Text fields, then don't use those. Use "Text Field"s for all text. They do everything that Static Text fields do (and lots more).

Comment: @AlexK  No, when I have static texts with English content, there is no problem. Could you for example copy the "سلام" word and paste it into a static text in your iReport? By the way I have tested it on different computers, but all share Windows 7!

Comment: to @mdahlman Text Fields are the same, I have not tested using resource bundles yet.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Yes. I've just test it - everything is ok. May be you should try to change default fonts in iReport.

Comment: That Persian text works well for me as well. I'm using iReport 4.7 on Mac OS X.

Comment: How to change the default fonts?

Comment: @mdahlman and where did you got the 4.7 version? The latest version on jasperforge.org site is 4.6

Comment: 4.7 is available with the commercial edition today (jaspersoft.com). But there is no change in this regard. iReport versions 4.6 and 4.5 work fine for me with that Persian text.